# Using De Moivre to show $\cos5\theta = P(\cos\theta)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Where $P$ is a polynomial of the 5th degree. I would understand how to show something like this if $P$ was given, but I'm not exactly sure how to approach this particular problem. I tried starting with $\cos5\theta = (\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)^5 - i\sin5\theta$ but I didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos 5\theta = Re [(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^5]$

or if your prefer

$\cos 5\theta = \frac 12 (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^5 + \frac 12 (\cos (-\theta) + i \sin (-\theta))^5$

either way you get:

$\cos 5\theta = \cos^5 \theta - 10 \cos^3\theta \sin^2 \theta + 5 cos \theta \sin^4\theta$

$\sin^2 \theta = (1-\cos^2\theta)$

$\cos 5\theta = \cos^5 \theta - 10 \cos^3\theta (1-\cos^2 \theta) + 5 \cos \theta (1-\cos^2\theta)^2$

multiply that out and you have a polynomial $p(\cos\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos 5\theta+i\sin5\theta=e^{i5\theta}=(cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^5=\cos^5\theta+5\cos^4\theta\cdot i\sin\theta-10\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta-10\cos^2\theta\cdot i\sin\theta+5\cos\theta\sin^4\theta+i\sin^5\theta$$

Now equate real part of left side to that of right side and then use $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$, you will find the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, solving this in the general case is substantially nicer than actually expanding everything out:

$$\cos(n\theta) = \mathrm{Re}\left(e^{in\theta}\right)$$

$$\cos(n\theta) = \mathrm{Re}\left((e^{i\theta})^n\right)$$

$$\cos(n\theta) = \mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(\cos\theta)^{n-k}(i\sin\theta)^{k} \right)$$

Note that the only times this is real is when $k$ is even:

$$\cos(n\theta) = \sum_{p=0}^{\left \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right \rfloor } {n\choose 2p}(\cos\theta)^{n-2p}(\sin^2\theta)^{p}(-1)^p $$

$$\cos(n\theta) = \sum_{p=0}^{\left \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right \rfloor } (-1)^p{n\choose 2p}(\cos\theta)^{n-2p}(1-\cos^2\theta)^{p} $$

which is a polynomial in $\cos\theta$.